# Stuck in a nested loop while using JMeter. Nested loop controller and CSV data set config.

Tags: jmeter

On my site I have two merchant actions: search and browse. A search normally triggers three browses.

I have a JMeter test which uses a CSV file of merchants and merchant id numbers, when running this test at scale I want all the merchants on my site to be used.

I have mapped this in JMeter like so:

- Loop Controller

  - HTTP Sampler (Search /search/${merchant_name})
  - CSV data set config (Merchant Name)
  - Loop Controller

    - HTTP Sampler (Browse /merchant/${merchant_id})
    - CSV data set Config (Merchant ID)

I set `loop count = 2` in the outer loop and `loop count = 3` in the inner loop.

I expect two searches to trigger 6 browse actions. But what I get is a search, followed by three browses, continually until I abort the test.

Have I misunderstood the loop construct? Is this the expected behaviour?

How can I achieve my goal of running a search, followed by three browses, twice?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're misusing CSV Data Set configuration.

I've got your scenario working as follows:

Given following CSV Files:

`merchants.csv` containing:

```
merchant1name
merchant2name
```

and 2 other CSV files: `merchant1name.csv` and `merchant2name.csv` with the contents of:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

And following Test Plan Structure:

- Thread Group (1 thread, 1 second ramp-up, 1 loop)

  - Loop Controller (2 loops)

    - HTTP Request /${merchantname}

      - Beanshell Post Processor (see below for code and explanation)
    - CSV Data Set Config (Filename: full path to your merchants.csv file, Variable names: merchantname, all defaults)
    - Loop Controller (3 loops)

      - HTTP Request /${merchantid}

        - CSV Data Set Config (Filename: full path to merchantname1 file, merchantname1 should be property, Variable name: merchantid, all defaults)

By using "all defaults" in regards to CSV Data Set Config I assume the following:

- File encoding - blank (my JMeter is running with UTF-8 which is fine for majority of cases)
- Delimiter - , (comma)
- Allow quoted data - false
- Recycle on EOF - true
- Stop Thread on EOF - false
- Sharing mode - all threads

Beanshell Code:

```
props.put("merchantname", vars.get("merchantname"));
```

This is required as CSV Data Config does not allow using variables in file path.

Path in inner loop:

```
C:\jmeter\${__P(merchantname,)}.csv
```

You can refer to http://glinius.narod.ru/stackoverflow/nestedloop.zip file. Unpack everything from "nestedloop" folder (1 jmx file and 3 CSV files) to /bin folder of JMeter and run the test. It'll produce 8 requests

Reference material:

1. [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)
2. [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)