# Looping two CSV files in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'd like to loop two csv files in Jmeter.  I found [this](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-looping-2-csv-files/) which is close, but I'd like the outer file to give me the CSV filename for the inner CSV.

So the outer file might have

```
filename
A
B
C
```

And this would lead to the inner loop looping

```
A.csv
B.csv
C.csv
```

When I try the technique referenced above, I get an error that the filename does not exist and I can see in the error that the problem is that jmeter is not substituting the variable in the filename for CSV data set under the Loop Controller.  I suspect jmeter evaluates all the variables at a time when the variable introduced by the outer CSV file are not yet defined.

Comment: Probable duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636775/jmeter-use-variable-as-csv-file-location?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible in JMeter using `CSv Data Set Config`.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not substituting a **variable**, but it will substitute a **property**.

Convert your variable into property and the approach will start working.

See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide to learn how you can do it and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866433/2897748) for working JMeter script realizing alike scenario.

Comment: OP wants to use 1 CSV dataset config to read 3 different CSV files by passing it name (variable / property). Will it work? I thought we could use 1 CSV data config for 1 csv file!!